# Retrieving values from excel, processing them and writing them in Python?

Tags: python

I am a beginner to Python.
I would like to retrieve values (URLs) from an excel file.
After that I want to apply conditions by using "if" statement and then write it to another excel file. Is that possible in Python?
*For example, this is the value in excel file: "www.b00tsrap.com"
I want to take that whole string and apply condition that if value contains a number, write "1" in a specific columns in (another) excel sheet. Or if URL length is greater than 25, write "1" in specific column.*

Comment: Try `pandas`. Without some sample there is no way to help you.

Comment: What type of sample?

Comment: Example of input and output. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes I wrote in question the example of input i.e. www.b00tsrap.com

Comment: What I want it, it read the string from a .csv file line by line. Then for each line it apply if condition.. For example I say that if the string contains "@" sign, print "1", else "0".

Comment: def process(line):
    if "@" in line:
        print
        '1'

with open('sample.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        process(line)



Is it correct? What I am missing?

Comment: sample.txt file contains this:

http://pavypai.net/update/
http://paypal.com-loginapps.com/
http://payslimit.com/
http://onlinemuhurtham.org/Educarevista01/imagesnw/acces/bookmark/index.php?email=abuse@eldridge.com.au
ht

Comment: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io